# Remove URL part and file extension with strstr

Tags: php

I tried function: strstr, but it has one problem. Suppose, the URL looks like:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php
```

With strstr, I am able to remove anything before '/', but I want just:

index

i.e., the actual name of the file without extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it always ends in .php you can do:

```
basename('http://www.example.com/index.php', '.php')
```

If it can end with other extensions, you can do:

```
if (preg_match('#([^/]+)\.\w+$#', 'http://www.example.com/index.php', $matches))
    $basename = $matches[1];
```

Comment: @reko_t: It may sometimes end with .html.

Comment: Edited my answer to take that into account.

Answer (score 6):

I would highly suggest using the PHP [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function:

```
$address = 'http://www.example.com/index.php';
$url = parse_url($address);
echo $url['host'];
```

There is no point reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

If the file type can change and you are sure there are no other . in the file name e.g. index.2.php then you can use

```
$filename = basename('http://www.example.com/index.php');
$filename = substr($filename, 0, strpos($filename, '.'));
```

Answer (score 3):

+1 cletus for the right tool for the right job, a proper URL parser. The regex hacks will fail for various query string stuff.

However it's the last path part being sought here not the host. So:

```
$url = parse_url($address);
$filename= array_pop(explode('/', $url['path']));
$filestem= explode('.', $filename)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

its very simple , no need for much code.

just do it manually and it will be automatically readed

just write your url like that

```
      http://www.example.com/index
```

and it will show your files as there is .php in the end.